# Two ice machine problem by using hypo-exponential distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, exponential-distribution

> Ice machine 1 is currently working. Ice machine 2 will be put in use at a time $t$ from now. If the lifetime of ice machine $i$ is exponential with rate $\lambda_i$, $i = 1, 2$, by using hypo-exponential distribution:
>   **a)** What is the probability that ice machine 2 is the first machine to fail?
>   **b)** What is the probability that both ice machines will be fail at the same time?

I have problem to understand this question for **(a)** is this the same meaning that
$$P(\text{Machine 2 fail first})= 1-P(\text{Machine 1 fail first})\\=1-\mathbb{P}(M_1 < M_2 + t) = 1-\mathbb{P}(M_1 - M_2 < t).$$
Also for **(b)** is this the same meaning of using the joint destiny function below?
$$f(m_1,m_2) = f_{M_1}(m_1)\ f_{M_2}(m_2) = \lambda_1\lambda_2e^{-\lambda_1 m_1}e^{-\lambda_2 m_2},\qquad m_1,m_2 > 0.$$

Comment: The likelihood of both machines failing at the exact same instant is 0. That will be true for any continuous distribution of failure times. Is that really what the question is asking?

Comment: Yes , can show mathematically how should be zero ?

Comment: P(M1 fails at time x) = 0 for all x. That's true of any continuous probability density function. P(M2 fails at time x) = 0 for all x. P(M1 and M2 fail at time x) = 0 for all x.

Comment: from your answer, if you integrate the P(M1 fails at time t) = 1 and same answer for M2 . because t>o for both.

Comment: It's unclear what the question is asking - what does it mean for "both machines to be fail at the same time"? If it's asking about the instant of failure, then P=0, as the machines will never fail at the same instant. If it's asking what the probability they are both inoperational at the same time, then P=1, as both machines will eventually break in the end.

Comment: what i understood the question asking about the probability they are both break down at the same time.